# PYTHON Mechanize Login form class

Tags: python, mechanize

I tried to use mechanize to login to the following form.

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-signin" id="form_login">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading"><center>GReAT Sinkhole Database</center></h2>
        <div id="form_login_error_box" class="form_error_box"></div>
        <label for="form_username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="form_username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        <label for="form_password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="form_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Mechanize browser Methodes `br.submit()` and `br.click()` didn't submit my form and I didn't retrieve the HTML wanted.

Here is the code

```
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form.set_value(login_user, nr=0)
browser.form.set_value(Loginpwd, nr=1)
ff = browser.submit()
print " title ##" + str(browser.title())
print ff.read()
```

What should be?

Comment: Maybe you selected the wrong form? Could you provide a page link or the full html?

Comment: If that was the case it would at least give me controll name error

Answer (score 2):

The `<form>` element does not have `method` or `action` attributes.

The default behaviour for forms with no method is to submit via a GET request, and as there is no action defined I guess they would submit to the url of the page (the HTML spec doesn't specify what happens if no action is defined).  It's unlikely that a login form would behave like this.

So it seems likely that this form is submitted via javascript, and isn't amenable to being accessed using Mechanize.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this problem in witch the form.submit seemed to have No effect

```
datat = {'username': 'ADMIN','password':'ADMIN'}
#Encode the parameters
data = urllib.urlencode(datat)
#Submit the form (POST request).
print "POST"
browser.open(post_url,data)
print "POSTED"
print browser.open(url_to_get).read()
```